# How can I create multiple routes using React Router v4 (Sidebar)?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have `JSON data` of cricket teams. The cricket app is basically CRUD web app where we can create new teams or delete existing team. I want to `map` each of the `sidebar routes` check this for example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar and display data for each of the team if I click on a particular team.

I have gone through the react router docs but the routes are hard coded but if I have dynamic list of cricket teams in sidebar how can I display data of a particular team onclicking particular team (See screenshot).

Routes in docs are:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    sidebar: () => <div>home!</div>,
    main: () => <h2>Home</h2>
  },
  {
    path: "/bubblegum",
    sidebar: () => <div>bubblegum!</div>,
    main: () => <h2>Bubblegum</h2>
  },
  {
    path: "/shoelaces",
    sidebar: () => <div>shoelaces!</div>,
    main: () => <h2>Shoelaces</h2>
  }
];
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You do not need route for all the sidebar countries. If i understand you correctly, then you just need one route for all the countries.

You route with something like /countries/:countryId as path and then based on match you decide what data to display. There probably is an answer for it already.

Comment: Do you mean the dynamic routing with *id*, *name* etc. as shown in another [section](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component) of the docs. It is achieved by a semicolon notation like: `<Route path="/user/:username" component={User}/>`. If you need another point to be clarified, add it in your question.

Comment: @vahdet Ok so if `:username` matches then display information of that user is that how it works ?

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb Ok so if `countryID` matches it should display that country but I couldn't get in docs regarding url matching. Can you please share it.

Comment: @stonerock see this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params. There is :id example there and you can see how it uses this match.params.id in view

Comment: React router v4 is covering most use cases. Just give your items id and concatenate path string with id. You have example of match object use case in React Router documentation. You can even sent object via query string if you need but this needs more customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes file you can specify a route like this:

```
<Route path="/teams/:teamId component={TeamDetails} />
```

And then in TeamDetails Component, you can access the teamId like:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

To have match in your props you have to use `withRouter`.

You can use withRouter as follows:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class TeamDetails extends React.Component {
    .....
    .....
}

export default withRouter(TeamDetails);
```

**Update for OP's comment:**

In your TeamDetails component:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class TeamDetails extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getTeam(this.props.match.params.id)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.team);
    return (......);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  teams: state.teams.team,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getTeams: teamId => dispatch(actions.getTeams(teamId)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(TeamDetails));
```

When your TeamDetails component loads you will call an action called getTeam which will inturn call api. And in your reducer you will set a state called team. That state (team) will be available to you as a prop in your component via connect helper.

Comment: I understood that with react-router `params` we can just render a single component but I just want to ask when `this.props.match.params.id` matches it should render cricket match details of that particular `id` So how will my component change for different cricket teamdetails.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer but it could be done in much simpler way without using redux.